# Loading .npy file takes over 30x longer if RAM usage is high

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-management, ram

Here is my RAM usage when loading a .npy file, deleting it with del, calling gc.collect, then loading it again. It behaves as expected and takes about 2.5 seconds.
[image]

Here is the same thing, but while I have other things loaded in memory so my total RAM usage is high.
It takes over 90 seconds to load and my usage does this zig zag pattern.
[image]

What is going on here? When I delete the array, garbage collect it, then load it again I expect the newly loaded array to just fit right in where the old one was, regardless of my total RAM usage. When it does this zig zag loading it takes way too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by an OS feature called [memory paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging).

In short, when the system runs out of memory, it has a mechanism to allocate additional free memory by moving infrequently accessed memory to a file.

However, this process can take a relatively long time because it involves writing to disk. See how the zigzag climbs instantly and descends slowly? This is because the bottleneck for climbing is access to physical memory, and the bottleneck for descending is access to disk.

Comment: I thought that was what's going on, I guess what I can't understand is if the memory is removed from the last array to make room for the new one by using del and gc.collect, why would it need to use memory paging? If it frees up a 10gb array in memory then immediately loads the same 10gb array, why wouldn't it just fit right where it was?

Comment: On my PC, just `del` immediately releases the memory. So there must be some other factor. You may want to add test code to your question if possible.

Comment: That's assuming that it (numpy, python, os) can predict that the new array will exactly fit in the space that was just freed up.  And there's no intervening actions.  Reloading the same array several times in a row is not normal for production code.

Comment: @ken del releases it in memory for me as well, as shown in the graph. The problem is that once I load the file up again it doesn't just put it back in memory again where it was. It acts like it doesn't have enough space even though it would have to because it just cleared up the exact space it needs.

Comment: That's because your (and probably most) OS's paging mechanism uses [least recently used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Least_recently_used) for its page replacement algorithm. Since you have allocated (used) memory for numpy, that memory segment is marked as "recently used". And OS thinks it is better to leave the MOST recently used segment in physical memory, so it moves the LEAST recently used segment to the paging file instead.